# Disable or hide taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

What is best module to hide or disable or un-publish some terms in taxonomy or vocabulary
like the way in the node tab of publishing in the back end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [taxonomy term status](https://www.drupal.org/project/termstatus) module is aimed at this use case.

There is an issue for that module regarding views exposed filters at https://www.drupal.org/node/1805882

Looking at that issue it is a little unclear the status of it. Some users say they have it working and others say they do not.
I would try adding your experiences to that issue and someone that has experience with that specific problem may be able to help you get it working.

Comment: Thanks for this fast response :) , i ll check it right now.

Comment: it worked for a quick test, i hope it would work with exposed form filter by views module. Thanks @rooby

Comment: It didn't work for exposed form generated by views
any help for this !? 
or do i have to manage it manually from exposed form alter ?

Comment: I added some more to my answer about that.

Comment: It working perfectly, it was my fault that i was testing it on wrong taxonomy term with same name but under another vocabulary :) 
Thanks again @rooby